# Явное указание class не работает для параметра-класса

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, c++20

Почему этот код не компилируется, хотя я явно указал, что передавать надо класс?

```
#include <concepts>
#include <type_traits>

template<class T>
concept Class = std::is_class_v<T>;

class A {

};

template<Class A>
void foo() {
    class A a;
}

int main(){
    foo<A>();
}
```

Comment: уберите здесь `class A a;` и все будет компилиться.

Comment: @KoVadim так почему не компилируется, если я явно указал, что там класс должен быть?

Comment: это не нужно. в чистом си это нужно было для структур и enum. Но только в этом случае struct/enum обозначал namespace типов. (вроде так это называется).

Comment: @KoVadim мне нужно

Comment: а можете объяснить, зачем? какой в этом плюс?

Comment: @KoVadim очевидно, что видно явно, что это класс, а не `int` какой-нибудь

Comment: ох ох. std::string - это класс? как будто. Но вот только `class std::string s;` - уже не работает. Плюс ко всему, у Вас уже есть прикрученный выше концепт, который уже решает поставленную задачу

Comment: @KoVadim я уже написал ниже, что только для своих классов

Comment: Не советую привыкать к "нетрадиционному" стилю написания кода. Если хотите наглядности, то лучше добавляйте какой-то префикс к названиям классов.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat чтобы привыкнуть, надо сначала заставить скомпилироваться :)

Comment: @ueber Ну, в других-то ситуациях это у вас работает.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat да. А почему тут не работает, знаете?

Comment: Пока не знаю, надо стандарт раскапывать... Минус такого подхода - можно случайно объявить новый класс, опечатавшись в названии существующего на одну букву. В большинстве случаев это сразу вызовет какую-то другую ошибку, но не везде.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Похоже, что внутри шаблона его шаблонные параметры-типы обрабатываются точно так же, как псевдонимы типов, созданные с помощью `typedef` или `using`. Стандарт называет их *typedef-name*.

> [`[temp.param]/3`](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.param#3)
>
> A *type-parameter* whose identifier does not follow an ellipsis defines its *identifier* to be a *typedef-name* (if declared without `template`) ...

Значит, ваш код не работает по той же причине, что и:

```
class A {};
using B = A;
class B b;
```

Справа от `class` может быть написано только настоящее имя класса, а не ссылающийся на него псевдоним.

> [`[dcl.type.elab]/2`](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.elab#2)
>
> ... If the *identifier* ... resolves to a *typedef-name* ..., the *elaborated-type-specifier* is ill-formed. ...

Здесь *elaborated-type-specifier* - это конструкция вида `class ИмяТипа` (вместо `class` может быть `struct`,`enum`,...). А под *identifier* имеется в виду как раз `ИмяТипа`, написанное справа от `class`.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
template<class T>
concept Class = std::is_class_v<T>;

template<Class A>
void foo() {
    A a;
}

class A {
};

int main(){
    foo<A>();
}
```

Странная у вас конструкция, однако -

```
class A a;
```

**Update**

Короче, если вам нужен в `foo()` объект класса `A`, который объявлен вне функции - пишите

```
template<Class B>
void foo() {
    class A a;
}
```

Если уж совсем не можете без этого `class` обходиться.

Если нужен объект именно того `A`, которое является параметром шаблона - то

```
template<Class A>
void foo() {
    A a;
}
```

Если хотите так, чтоб нарушить правила языка и компилировалось - то тогда придумывайте самостоятельно...

Comment: так почему не компилируется, если я явно указал, что там класс должен быть?

Comment: Вы, когда переменную типа `Type` объявляете, всегда пишете `class Type a;`? Типа, `class string s;`? Или нет? Просто `string s;`?

Comment: Для своих классов пишу

Comment: Поставил до функции объявление класса, но всё равно не пашет

Comment: Поставьте `template<Class B>`, и все получится :) Вы уж решите, что вы хотите - чтобы в функции была переменная `a` того же типа, что и параметр шаблона, или объект описанного вне шаблона класса `A`...

Comment: Изменил название параметра, но всё равно не пашет. Если вы имели в виду только параметр переназвать, а не тип `a`, то это не то что мне нужно - в таком случае нет смысла в шаблоне вообще

Comment: См. обновленный ответ.